# How to solve $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) +5n$ using iteration method?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

How can i solve $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) +5n$ using iteration method to find time complexity of the requrrence?

Comment: Why do you believe you can solve this relation with the iteration method? I'm certain there's no simple closed form here...

Comment: You can solve the relation using whatever method you want to use, i wrote that because i know one method now.

Comment: What is "time complexity of the recurrence"? And why do you think there is a solution? $n/3$ may not be an integer?

Comment: @JCAA It is a result of our bad educational system, unfortunately i have to deal with this. My teacher says the solution is O(n) but i don't know the way of solve that.

Comment: It's easy to see that $T(n)=12\,n$ is a solution. But so is $T(n)=12\,n+c\,n^\alpha,$ where $\alpha$ is the solution of $3^{-\alpha}+4^{-\alpha}=1$ (it's slightly bigger than $1/2$), for any value of $c$.